# Implement Matlab Syntax in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, syntax, operator-overloading

In Matlab the syntax to add elements to a matrix is

```
A = [12 62 93 -8 22; 16 2 87 43 91; -4 17 -72 95 6]
A =
    12    62    93    -8    22
    16     2    87    43    91
    -4    17   -72    95     6
```

I am building a small matrix library for educational purposes in C++ , 
the best way I have been able to come up with is to create an array and use list initialization , but it won't work for my purposes.

I need to be able to know how many rows are columns are there first so as to initialize the matrix.

Is there any way to copy this syntax in C++ . I would like the user to be able to create a matrix using a convenient method , rather than creating a matrix and going through each element , add a value .

I can handle the = using operator overloading , but what do I do about the right hand side. How do I deal with the [ ] or ; . I don't specifically need the colons or braces . Any other syntax will do too , as long as it is convenient for the user.

I realize it will be too much to ask you to implement it . All I want is some heuristic on how to do this , or a link with relevant information.

-Thank you

Comment: Sketch: If you are OK with dynamically sized matrices you can use the comma operator overloaded to cat value/vectors/matrices column-wise and the pipe operator overloaded to cat value/vectors/matrices row-wise and use move-semantics to reduce your copies. With that in mind, you would still need your own types otherwise weird things would happen...so you might still have to follow the above ^. Or you can do what [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ade5d2e09de50c2ca145037f295542b16) does....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *The C++ Programming Language (4th edition)*, *Chapter 29*, Stroutrup implements a `Matrix` class that satisfy your requirements. **C++11 is required**, though.

In particular, it can be initialized this way:

```
Matrix<int,2> m = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

In particular, in *§29.4.4*, he define `Matrix_init`, a nested `initializer_list`, that is what you are looking for. `Matrix_init<T,N>` simply has `Matrix_init<T,N-1>` as its member type:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Matrix_init {
    using type = initializer_list<typename Matrix_init<T,N-1>::type>;
};

// specialization for N = 1
template<typename T>
struct Matrix_init<T,1> {
    using type = initializer_list<T>;
};
```

You can now write:

```
Matrix_init<int, 2>::type m{ {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

or, through a template alias,

```
template<typenameT,size_t N>
using Matrix_initializer = typename Matrix_init<T,N>::type;

Matrix_initializer<int,2> m{ {1,2}, {3,4} };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd recommend it, but one obvious possibility would be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A = { 
    { 12 62 93 -8 22 },
    { 16 2 87 43 91  }, 
    { -4 17 -72 95 6 }
};
```

As long as it's purely educational, and you don't care a lot about wasting some space and the data not being contiguous, it should be fine.